# iPhone: How to draw localized text with with character spacing and multiply blend mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, character, blend

I'm trying to draw localized text (i.e., the text could be in english, chinese, arabic, etc.) with character spacing and multiply blend mode (`CGContextSetBlendMode`, `kCGBlendModeMultiply`).

If I use `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` I'm able to adjust character spacing (`CGContextSetCharacterSpacing`) and blend mode (`CGContextSetBlendMode`, `kCGBlendModeMultiply`), but I get strange characters instead of the localized string.

If I use `NSString` `drawAtPoint:withFont` it works fine to draw the localized text but I'm not able to modify character spacing nor the blend mode. The strange thing is that I'm able to adjust the shadow with `CGContextSetShadow`. Thus, shouldn't I be able to adjust the character spacing as well?

Is it possible to adjust character spacing and blend mode with `NSString` `drawAtPoint:withFont`? Or which encoding to use so that the localized text is showed correctly in all languages the the iPhone support?

iOS4 will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: Core Text is the way to go.